# How to fix div hover to display correctly without missing sides?

Tags: html, css

I have div that have box-shadow on it and have also div:hover box-shadow.

When i check results at JSfiddle its all fine.

But when i check the results at my site i get the box-shadow right side **removed**:

[image]

Here is the Live code: [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/73xu5nrd/2/)

And here is the Code:

```css
.nitz {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 76px;
  direction: rtl;
  background-color: #e4e5e8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) 0px 0px 0px 1000px, 
              inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0px 1px 0px, 
              inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0px 0px 0px 1px, 
                    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
}
.nitz:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 6px rgba(251, 219, 90, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 6px rgba(251, 219, 90, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 6px rgba(251, 219, 90, 1);
  background-color: #f8f8f9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.boxtitle1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.boxtitle2 {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.Cellbox2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" rel="">
  <div class="nitz">
    <div class="Cellbox2">
      <div class="boxtitle1">That is a big test</div>
      <div class="boxtitle2">That is a small one</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

The over Divs are:

**ipsWidget ipsWidget_vertical ipsBox**

**ipsWidget ipsWidget_vertical ipsBox**

and

**ipsList_reset**

above all that divs.

The css of that divs are:

```
/* Blocks - styles for various widgets */

.ipsWidget {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
}

.ipsWidget.ipsWidget_vertical {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

    .ipsWidget.ipsWidget_vertical .ipsWidget_title {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        background: {theme="widget_title_bar"};
        border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    }

.ipsWidget_inner{
        padding: 10px;
}

    .ipsWidget.ipsWidget_vertical .ipsWidget_inner {
        color: #575757;

    }

.ipsWidget.ipsWidget_horizontal {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

    .ipsWidget.ipsWidget_horizontal:not( .ipsWidgetHide ) + .ipsWidget {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

        .ipsWidget.ipsWidget_horizontal .ipsWidget_title {
            font-weight: 400;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            background: #f5f5f5;
            padding: 10px;
        }

    .ipsWidget.ipsWidget_vertical .ipsWidget_inner {
        color: #575757;
    }

    .ipsWidget.ipsWidget_horizontal .ipsTabs {
        margin: -5px 0 5px 0;
    }

        .ipsWidget.ipsWidget_horizontal .ipsTabs_panel {
            background: #fff;
            margin: 0;
        }

.ipsWidget_columns > [class*="ipsGrid"] {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

html[dir="ltr"] .ipsWidget_columns > [class*="ipsGrid"] {
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding-right: 10px;
}
html[dir="rtl"] .ipsWidget_columns > [class*="ipsGrid"] {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    padding-left: 10px;
}

    html[dir="ltr"] .ipsWidget_columns > [class*="ipsGrid"]:last-child {
        border-right: 0;
    }
    html[dir="rtl"] .ipsWidget_columns > [class*="ipsGrid"]:last-child {
        border-left: 0;
    }

.ipsWidget_horizontal .ipsWidget_statsCount {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 32px !important;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.ipsWidget_horizontal .ipsWidget_stats {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.ipsWidget .ipsTabs_small {
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
}

    .ipsWidget .ipsTabs_small .ipsTabs_item:not( .ipsTabs_activeItem ) {
        color: rgba(50,50,50,0.6);
        border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    .ipsWidget .ipsTabs_small .ipsTabs_activeItem {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    }

.ipsWidget .ipsDataItem_title {
    font-size: 13px;
}

.ipsWidget.ipsWidget_primary {
    background: #262e33;
}

    .ipsWidget.ipsWidget_primary h3 {
        color: #fff;
    }

html[dir="ltr"] .ipsWidget_latestItem {
    margin-left: 85px;
}
html[dir="rtl"] .ipsWidget_latestItem {
    margin-right: 85px;
}

.ipsWidgetBlank {
    margin-top: 16px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: link to your site?

Comment: Cant give that. Sorry

Comment: Add more value to margin-right of cellbox or add your full code.

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help you. If you can't link your site, then make a fiddle ***which has the problem***, and post that instead.

Comment: @4castle i'm pretty sure he thought that exemple was minimal and complete and doesn't realise that it's a side effect of the rest of his code though...

Comment: @Carele The issue is that it's not verifiable. All we can do is guess how the other code is different.

Comment: Yeah you're right. But i'm wondering if the implicite question there is not "how to guess what is different so i can make a minimal code"... Not saying his question is correct but he might need a little bit of help to improve it...

Comment: @Carele You're right. They will have to guess and choose what to include until they are able to reproduce it. Asking people to make an MCVE is asking them to do some debugging, and often times people discover the problem in the process. SO is less about identifying the cause, and more about identifying the solution.

Comment: Im really sorry but right now i cant give my site address.

Comment: @StackBuck then try to add enough code so that we can help you. Give us the full css of the wrapping divisions around the buttons maybe ?

Comment: I add more information

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem does not come from the code you linked.
Rather i guess that your button is on the border of a `overflow : hidden` div and the shadow falls outshide that div.
Or there is another invisible div beside the button hidding the shadow.

Look at that snippet and notice why part of the shadow doesn't show : The button is on the top right corner of the parent (".test") div.
I cannot check your code but i guess the problem comes from a parent div (maybe because you haven't fixed a width and it is stopping right after the button)

```css
.test {
  display: block
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nitz {
  font-family:sans-serif; 
  font-size: 0; 
  float: right;
  width:300px; 
  height:76px; 
  direction:rtl; background-color:#e4e5e8;border-radius: 5px;
display:block;
box-shadow: inset rgba(255,255,255,0.75) 0px 0px 0px 1000px, 
  inset rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 0px 1px 0px, 
  inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0px 0px 0px 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
}

.nitz:hover {-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 6px rgba(251,219,90,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 6px rgba(251,219,90,1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 6px rgba(251,219,90,1);
background-color:#f8f8f9;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.boxtitle1 {font-weight: bold;text-align:right; font-size:14px; padding-bottom:3px;}
.boxtitle2 {text-align:right; font-size:14px;}
    

.Cellbox1 
{width:50px; height:50px; display:inline-block;  margin-bottom:15px; margin-right:15px; margin-top:15px; }
.Cellbox2 
{display:inline-block; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom:15px; vertical-align:top; margin-top:20px;}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<a href="https://www.google.com" rel="">
<div class="nitz">      
 
      
   <div class="Cellbox2">
<div class="boxtitle1">That is a big test</div>

<div class="boxtitle2">That is a small one</div>
  </div>
     </div>
     </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: It is under another divs but there's no overflow : hidden there

Comment: Try to enlarge the other div or move the button in the div to see if the border of the shadow reappears. Or if you can give a link to a working exemple i could give you more insights.

Comment: I add to '.ipsWidget .ipsWidget_vertical .ipsBox' the '.test' div paragraphs but it was not display the whole sides with glow like i want.

Comment: My snippet wasn't meant to solve your problem. It was a reproduction of your bug to make up understand where the problem comes from. since i don't have the code of the container i cannot give you a definitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some padding to the parent "anchor" tag with some classname

```
.some-class-name {
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: It takes the box or the content inside to the left but not solve the problem